# Getting limited information from JSON with Python

Tags: python, json

I would like to extract only particular positions out of JSON with Python. I am interested in all entries in "data" (see code below). The entries that I am intersted are "4101" and "3591". I am not interested in any details that are in deeper levels. How can I get a list of entries. My end result should be something like output = ["4101", "3591", and so on..]

I am using json.dump n Python.
Are there any attributes that I could add to json.dump(records)? Like json.dump(records,findonly="data", depth="1")?

```
records = """{
"status": "ok",
"count": 130,
"data": {
    "4101": {
        "is_gift": false,
        "nation_i18n": "Japan",
        "name": "type-91",
        "level": 1,
        "nation": "japan",
        "is_premium": false,
        "plane_id": 4101,
        "images": {
            "small": "http://worldofwarplanes.eu/static/1.1.0/encyclopedia/planopedia/vehicle/small/type-91.png",
            "large": "http://worldofwarplanes.eu/static/1.1.0/encyclopedia/planopedia/vehicle/large/type-91.png",
            "medium": "http://worldofwarplanes.eu/static/1.1.0/encyclopedia/planopedia/vehicle/medium/type-91.png"
        },
        "name_i18n": "Nakajima Type-91",
        "type": "fighter"
    },
    "3591": {......[it goes on and on]
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far? And where are you stuck?

Comment: Based on your "question" i'd say you are looking for: `output = ["4101", "3591", and so on..]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`json.load()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) to parse the JSON into a Python data structure, and then access whatever contents you need:

```
json_file = open('data.json')
dct = json.load(json_file)
print dct['data'].keys()
```

Output:

```
[u'4101', u'3591']
```

Comment: Thank You,
What about selecting some key values inside the 'data'? For example, I am interested in getting value of "name" for each entry in 'data'. I would expect to have an output similar to:
` [[u'4101','type-91], [u'3591','othername']] `

Comment: Use `dct['data'][key]` to access a particular value in the dictionary. If you want to get all of them, use a [`for` loop](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) or a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score -1):

As all the entries I seek are 4 digit numbers I went for regexp:

```
result = re.findall('\d{4}', record)
print result
```

Comment: So if **anywhere** else in the document there's a 4 digit string you'll use that as well? That's a terrible way of extracting information from structured data.